# is there a way to filter table using 3 or more ng-multiselect-dropdowns?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm loading items to dropdown of 4 (ng-multiselect-dropdowns) through json array variable from a api.
Also i'm using same json array variable which contain all information to display the data related to dropdowns on a html table.

I want to filter the table based on mutiple selection of all the dropdowns(It's just like AND operation between dropdowns).

how to do this? Using code example would be  really helpful.

Comment: can you share whaat you have done first, may be in a stackblitz or fiddle

Comment: i'm really in a hurry. i just need the idea. also i have implemented those 4 dropdown's and can filter the table based on selection of individual dropdown. but not able to implement AND operation between dropdown's. i'll surely post a stackblitz by end of today, if i'm unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

it's just write some like (you has a few data)

```
this.filteredTable=this.table.filter(x=>this.variable.indexOf(x.id)>=0)
```

where in variable you has the "array" from the selected multiselect.

NOTE: if in your selected multiselected you has an array of object, make first

```
const search=this.variable.map(x=>x.id)
```

If you has severals selected, can be like

```
this.filteredTable=this.table.filter(x=>this.variable.indexOf(x.id)>=0 
       && this.variable2.indexOf(x.id2)>=0)
```